# lambda function equivalent for SUMIF() in python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns, "Industry Code", and "Amount". How can I sum all instances of Amount according to its Industry Code on a single lambda function? (the equivalent of sumif() in excel) I have tried the below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpvEE.png)

```
fun= lambda x,y: sum(x[i])/len(x[i]) in y[i]
```

I am getting the result `<function __main__.<lambda>>`
Any ideas?

Comment: PEP8 specifically states that you shouldn't work with named lambdas: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51 "Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier."

Comment: Can you explain why it is important that you do this with a lambda function? Where is your [mcve]? And what is the expected result?

Comment: The expected result is to apply that lambda to an optimization problem as a constraint e.g {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x.sum()-100}.

Answer (score 1):

`lambda` creates a function, and that is what you are assigning to `fun`.  You need to apply that function to arguments in order to do the summing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `groupby`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Aero', 'Energy', 'Aero', 'Hydra', 'Energy'],
                  [2, 5, 8, 6, 5]]).T
df.columns=['industry', 'amount']
df
   industry amount
0   Aero    2
1   Energy  5
2   Aero    8
3   Hydra   6
4   Energy  5

df.groupby('industry').sum()
        amount
industry    
Aero    10
Energy  10
Hydra   6
```

Comment: Thanks meW. I have used used groupby, but I am trying to find a lambda solution to apply as a constraint in an optimization problem using minimize().